# Is there any way to handle chrome popup unblocking via javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popupwindow

I am using window.open(url,'_blank') to open a url inside an iframe. But site is not opening and its showed as popup blocked. Is there any way to enable popup via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually enable the popup on the URL right side of chrome, there should not be any way of automatically unblocking the popup using javascript as it will just defeat the purpose of popup blocking and all popups from all webpages will just go do that and show.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a popup which checks the popups are enable or not.

If browser popup disable then you can show an alert or prompt to inform the user. And on click of prompt ok button you can just white your java Script code.